# SQL Server stored procedure input multiple variables into a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to create a temporary table and populate it with temporary values. The variables have values assigned from a python script. My code is as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddScrapedInfoBULK] 
    (
    -- Parameters for the SP, (each field in the all tables)
    -- ProjectInfo Fields
    @ProjectInfoID AS INT,
    @OrderNumber AS NVARCHAR(255),
    @PeriodofPerformance AS NVARCHAR(255),
    @POPEndDate AS DATETIME,
    @PopStartDate AS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @temproj TABLE (ProjectInfoID INT,
                            OrderNumber NVARCHAR(255),
                            PeriodofPerformance NVARCHAR(255),
                            POPEndDate DATETIME,
                            PopStartDate DATETIME)

    INSERT INTO @temproj 
        SELECT (@ProjectInfoID,
                @OrderNumber,
                @PeriodofPerformance,
                @POPEndDate,
                @PopStartDate)
END
```

but this does not work. How can I populate a temporary table with variables?

Comment: That doesn't even compile as written.

Comment: I know it doesn't. Usually this would work with some modification if i wanted to select values from a table, but i've never tried to insert only variables into a temp table.

Comment: FYI, @temproj is a table variable not a temp (# or ##) table. Table variables disappear instantly once you leave the procedure/batch where as # and ## tables have a different lifetime.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean thanks, i misspoke in my post because dropping the table variable after running is the desired functionality.

Comment: No worries, but since your posted code didn't do anything after inserting into the table variable, I thought you might think you could reference that table variable after the stored procedure would execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the parentheses around the select.

```
DECLARE    @ProjectInfoID AS INT,
    @OrderNumber AS NVARCHAR(255),
    @PeriodofPerformance AS NVARCHAR(255),
    @POPEndDate AS DATETIME,
    @PopStartDate AS DATETIME

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @temproj TABLE (ProjectInfoID INT,
                            OrderNumber NVARCHAR(255),
                            PeriodofPerformance NVARCHAR(255),
                            POPEndDate DATETIME,
                            PopStartDate DATETIME)

    INSERT INTO @temproj 
        SELECT @ProjectInfoID,
                @OrderNumber,
                @PeriodofPerformance,
                @POPEndDate,
                @PopStartDate
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use  `insert into .... values` to make it.

```
INSERT INTO @temproj 
            (projectinfoid, 
             ordernumber, 
             periodofperformance, 
             popenddate, 
             popstartdate) 
VALUES      (@ProjectInfoID, 
             @OrderNumber, 
             @PeriodofPerformance, 
             @POPEndDate, 
             @PopStartDate)
```

Comment: @DBA108642 . . . This is the better solution.  Not only was it first, but listing the columns on an insert is a best practice that should be encouraged.